# Application won't start after upgrade from EclipseLink 2.1.3 to EclipseLink 2.4 Nightly

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have upgraded my Eclipse IDE to Juno from Helios. I have updated my projects to use the latest version of EclipseLink that came with Juno which is 2.4 Nightly (as displayed in the Persistance properties). I have one project that is itself a JPA project (ProjectA) that has a dependancy on another JPA project (ProjectB). So in effect, I have a project that is talking to 2 seperate databases. When I try to start ProjectA running under Tomcat I get the exception listed below. The entities referred to in the exception are all located in the dependant project - ProjectB. I've rebuilt both projects and re-deployed.

I'm wondering if 2.4 is not a straight upgrade from 2.1.3 and I've missed some upgrade documentation somewhere detailing changes I need to make to the config of my JPA projects.

Reverting both ProjectA and ProjectB back to EclipseLink 2.1.3, everything works correctly

I've listed part of the exception for only one of the entities to save space, but it repeats for every entity defined in Project B.

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20110816-r9894):   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [_persistence_set_platform_vh] or [_persistence_get_platform_vh] is not defined in the object [com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcuAcronym].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcuAcronym._persistence_get_platform_vh()
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[platform]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcuAcronym --> [DatabaseTable(pecuacronym)])
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.noSuchMethodWhileInitializingAttributesInMethodAccessor(DescriptorException.java:1170)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.MethodAttributeAccessor.initializeAttributes(MethodAttributeAccessor.java:200)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.MethodAttributeAccessor.initializeAttributes(MethodAttributeAccessor.java:181)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.preInitialize(DatabaseMapping.java:1276)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.preInitialize(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ObjectReferenceMapping.preInitialize(ObjectReferenceMapping.java:1054)
at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.preInitialize(ClassDescriptor.java:3571)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:493)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:476)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:435)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:673)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:618)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:474)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:290)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:268)
at com.blackbox.dao.JpaBaseDao.findAll(JpaBaseDao.java:50)
at com.blackbox.services.Services.listAllPlatforms(Services.java:70)
at com.blackbox.services.Services.listAllPublishedPlatforms(Services.java:355)
at com.blackbox.x.actions.diagnostics.IdentifyVehicle.prepare(IdentifyVehicle.java:42)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:162)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.blackbox.x.interceptors.Log4jMDCInterceptor.intercept(Log4jMDCInterceptor.java:51)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.blackbox.x.interceptors.RedirectMessageInterceptor.doIntercept(RedirectMessageInterceptor.java:78)
at com.blackbox.x.interceptors.RedirectMessageInterceptor.intercept(RedirectMessageInterceptor.java:63)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsExecuteFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:82)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:323)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1719)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcuAcronym._persistence_get_platform_vh()
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.findMethod(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:82)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getMethod(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:283)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper.getDeclaredMethod(Helper.java:974)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.MethodAttributeAccessor.initializeAttributes(MethodAttributeAccessor.java:193)
... 94 more
```

To be clear - if I deploy ProjectB on it's own then it works as expected. The problem only happens when I deploy JPA Project A which has a dependancy on ProjectB that the problem occurs. ProjectA opens it's own persistance context correctly, but not ProjectB's.

I have attached the persistance.xml as requested.

ProjectA;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Genesis" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.SecurityKey</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.QualifiedSecurityKey</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.User</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.Password</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.ServiceDefinition</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.IdsFunction</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.FaultCodeType</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.FaultCodeDescription</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.VehicleActivityLogEntry</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.Recovery</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.SingleVehicleLicense</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.MultiVehicleLicense</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.License</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.LicenseGroupMaster</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.LicenseGroup</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.FunctionGroup</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.McodeText</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.CCFParameterMaster</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.CCFFunctionGroup</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.CCFParameterOptionUsage</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.CCFAsBuiltIndex</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.CCFEditLog</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.AsBuiltAnalyzerFileTracker</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.CCFParameterOption</class>
    <class>com.blackbox.x.entities.JlrVersionControl</class>


<properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="userId"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="<elided>"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and ProjectB;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ids2_develop" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

<description>Eclipse</description>
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.Vw_Ecu</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.SwimPart</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.SoftwarePK</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.Software</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.ServiceData</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.PlatformData</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.Platform</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcuTextPK</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcuText</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcuAcronymPK</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcuAcronym</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.PEcu</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.PBusPK</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.PBus</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.Manufacturer</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.HardwarePK</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.Hardware</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.CusCom</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.CCFParameter</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.CCFGroup</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.Bus</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.BBoxCom</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.AssemblyPK</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.Assembly</class>
<class>com.blackbox.entities.db.McodeLookupKey</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="<elided>"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="ids2dbuser"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ids2"/> 
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.native-sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.Vw_Ecu" value="NONE"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Sounds like a static weaving problem. Your entities are probably weaved with the older version. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402343/eclipselink-static-weaved-entities-breaks-remove-of-an-entity-operation

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a weaving issue.  It looks like weaving did not occur for the object.  Ensure you have weaving enabled correctly.  If you are using static weaving, make sure you use 2.4 the statically weave your classes.

Try disabling weaving to confirm the issue.  Also include your persistence.xml.